# HTML Input Required is messing up my input

Tags: css, html

So I dont want to use the "Required" attribute, but in my  if I dont put it in there it completely messes up the way I want my form to look.

[image: The top "Email" input is the one with the required attribute and the bottom does not haveit.]

So why does removing this change it? Its setup so when you click Email it will then move out of the way and look like the one that says password.

here is my html for this:

```
    <form action="./includes/login.inc.php" method="post">
        <div class="group">
            <input type="text" name="emailuid" required=""/><span class="highlight"></span><span class="bar"></span>
            <label>Email</label>
        </div>
        <div class="group">
            <input type="password" name="pwduid"/><span class="highlight"></span><span class="bar"></span>
            <label>Password</label>
        </div>
        <div class="btn-box">
            <button class="btn btn-submit" type="submit" name="login-submit">Sign in</button>
        </div>
    </form>
```

And here is my CSS styling (Just for the forms!)

```
form {
  width: 320px;
  margin: 45px auto;
}
form h1 {
  font-size: 3em;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2196F3;
}
form h5 {
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #c6c6c6;
}
form hr.sep {
  background: #2196F3;
  box-shadow: none;
  border: none;
  height: 2px;
  width: 25%;
  margin: 0px auto 45px auto;
}
form .emoji {
  font-size: 1.2em;
}

.group {
  position: relative;
  margin: 45px 0;
}

textarea {
  resize: none;
}

input,
textarea {
  background: none;
  color: #4F4F4F;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 5px;
  display: block;
  width: 320px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #4F4F4F;
}
input:focus,
textarea:focus {
  outline: none;
}
input:focus ~ label, input:valid ~ label,
textarea:focus ~ label,
textarea:valid ~ label {
  top: -14px;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #FF3B3F;
}
input:focus ~ .bar:before,
textarea:focus ~ .bar:before {
  width: 335px;
}

input[type="password"] {
  letter-spacing: 0.3em;
}

label {
  color: #4F4F4F;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: normal;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  left: 5px;
  top: 10px;
  -webkit-transition: 300ms ease all;
  transition: 300ms ease all;
}

.bar {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 320px;
}
.bar:before {
  content: '';
  height: 2px;
  width: 0;
  bottom: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  background: #FF3B3F;
  -webkit-transition: 300ms ease all;
  transition: 300ms ease all;
  left: 0%;
}

.btn {
  background: #fff;
  color: #959595;
  border: none;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  letter-spacing: 0.06em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.8, 0.25, 1);
  transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.8, 0.25, 1);
}
.btn:hover {
  color: #752021;
  box-shadow: 0 7px 14px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.18), 0 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
}
.btn.btn-link {
  background: #FF3B3F;
  color: #d3eafd;
}
.btn.btn-link:hover {
  background: #0d8aee;
  color: #deeffd;
}
.btn.btn-submit {
  background: #FF3B3F;
  color: white;
}
.btn.btn-submit:hover {
  background: #752021;
  color: white;
}
.btn.btn-cancel {
  background: #eee;
}
.btn.btn-cancel:hover {
  background: #e1e1e1;
  color: #8b8b8b;
}

.btn-box {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 50px 0;
}
```

I'm just so confused why its forcing my use the required attribute, I don't want to use it as I made a php checker to see if the fields are empty. And this is messing with my styling of how I want it to look.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TLDR;** Change this code:

```
input:focus ~ label,
input:valid ~ label,
textarea:focus ~ label,
textarea:valid ~ label
{
  top: -14px;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #FF3B3F;
}
```

To this:

```
input:focus ~ label,
textarea:focus ~ label
{
  top: -14px;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #FF3B3F;
}
```

---

**The explanation:**

Believe it or not, CSS styling can be applied to elements that specifically have certain attributes, so you should always be sure to check for pseudo classes corresponding to these attributes in your CSS. Example: `input:required {...}` corresponds to the `required` HTML attribute on an `input` element.

To make things even more complicated, the `required` attribute can determine if other pseudo classes such as `:valid`, are activated on that element. So, if an element is set to `required`, but the field isn't filled out properly, any CSS specifying the `:invalid` pseudo-class will automatically be activated. If it is filled out properly, the `:valid` pseudo-class CSS properties will take effect.

Comment: so if I were to get rid of 'input:valid', it should work properly without it needing the Required attribute?

Comment: Possibly-- you'll probably have to experiment a bit (ah, the joy of CSS). I'll double-check your provided code and see if I can give you an exact solution.

Comment: Just to clarify, you want the password label to move up, like the email label does?

Comment: yes, I’m trying to get the Label to move up when you click on it. But it only moves up when the ‘required=“”’ is in the <input>. Thanks for double checking it

Comment: Okay so i got rid of what you said to remove, it still doesn’t show the grey text that moves up still without the input attribute Required, This is really baffling me

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187352/discussion-between-jknotek-and-corey-rinda).

Answer (score 2):

So `input:valid ~ label` in your css was causing the problem.
Try this:

```css
form {
  width: 320px;
  margin: 45px auto;
}
.group {
  position: relative;
  margin: 45px 0;
}
input {
  background: none;
  color: #4F4F4F;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 5px;
  display: block;
  width: 320px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #4F4F4F;
}
input:focus {
  outline: none;
}
input:focus ~ label {
  top: -14px;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #FF3B3F;
}
input:focus ~ .bar:before {
  width: 335px;
}

input[type="password"] {
  letter-spacing: 0.3em;
}

label {
  color: #4F4F4F;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: normal;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  left: 5px;
  top: 10px;
  -webkit-transition: 300ms ease all;
  transition: 300ms ease all;
}

.bar {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 320px;
}
.bar:before {
  content: '';
  height: 2px;
  width: 0;
  bottom: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  background: #FF3B3F;
  -webkit-transition: 300ms ease all;
  transition: 300ms ease all;
  left: 0%;
}

.btn {
  background: #fff;
  color: #959595;
  border: none;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  letter-spacing: 0.06em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.8, 0.25, 1);
  transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.8, 0.25, 1);
}
.btn:hover {
  color: #752021;
  box-shadow: 0 7px 14px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.18), 0 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
}
.btn.btn-link {
  background: #FF3B3F;
  color: #d3eafd;
}
.btn.btn-link:hover {
  background: #0d8aee;
  color: #deeffd;
}
.btn.btn-submit {
  background: #FF3B3F;
  color: white;
}
.btn.btn-submit:hover {
  background: #752021;
  color: white;
}
.btn.btn-cancel {
  background: #eee;
}
.btn.btn-cancel:hover {
  background: #e1e1e1;
  color: #8b8b8b;
}

.btn-box {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 50px 0;
}
```

```html
<form action="#" method="post">
  <div class="group">
    <input type="text" name="emailuid"/><span class="highlight"></span><span class="bar"></span>
    <label>Email</label>
  </div>
  <div class="group">
    <input type="password" name="pwduid"/><span class="highlight"></span><span class="bar"></span>
    <label>Password</label>
  </div>
  <div class="btn-box">
    <button class="btn btn-submit" type="submit" name="login-submit">Sign in</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: When i run your code on here it works but when i paste it over into my editing software it still doesn’t work, i have another style sheet for my page, could there possible be something in there causing it to mess up?

Comment: checked, there was no other “input:valid” or anything consisting “valid” in the other style sheet

Comment: Then it would be little tough ! :p    
Check for these `:required`, `:optional`, `:valid`, `:invalid`